# Tpm2 not listing sha1 PCR banks

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, sha1, tpm

My hp-15 notebook laptop has Ubuntu 20.04 and I installed tpm2-tools and  when I list tpm2_pcrread it does not show sha1 PCR banks only sha256 is listing kindly help on this

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to check which algorithms are supported on your device:

```
tpm2_getcap pcrs
```

Maybe your version takes sha256 as default, try running

```
tpm2_pcrread sha1
```

to explicitly get the sha1 values.

One more thing, this question is not directly related to programming, [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tpm) is better suited for such questions.